# Expected Meeting Times of two persons in Random Walk on an $n$-Cycle

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Consider an  $n$-cycle labeled as $ \{0, 1, \dots, n-1\} $. Two individuals, person $ A $ and person $B$, perform random walks on this cycle. **At each step, both individuals move simultaneously and independently of each other.** Each person has a $0.5$ probability of moving one step clockwise and a $0.5$ probability of moving one step counterclockwise. Initially, the positions of person $A$ and person $B$ are such that they are separated by $k$ positions, meaning $i - j \equiv k \mod n $, where $i$ and $j$ represent the positions of person $A$ and person $B$, respectively.

**What is the expected time for the two individuals to encounter each other, meaning they occupy the same position?**

**My Idea:**

Instead of considering both persons $ A $ and $ B $ moving, we can keep person $ A $ fixed and adjust the movement probabilities for person $ B $. Specifically, $ B $ moves 2 steps forward with a probability of 0.25, 2 steps backward with a probability of 0.25, and doesn't move with a probability of 0.5.

Let $ X_i $ denote the expected time for the two to meet when they are separated by $ i $ positions.

The equation for $ X_i $ is:
$$ X_i = 0.5 X_i + 0.25 X_{(i-2) \mod n} + 0.25 X_{(i+2) \mod n} + 1 $$
for $ i \neq 0 $.

From this, we derive the following system of linear equations:
$$ X_0 = 0 $$
$$ X_i = 2 + \frac{1}{2} (X_{(i-2) \mod n} + X_{(i+2) \mod n}) $$
for $ 1 \le i \le (n-1) $.

The question then arises:

**How can we find an analytic solution for $X_i$ depending on $n$ and $i$?**

In fact, there are scenarios where the two individuals will never meet; for instance, when $n=4$ and $k=1$.

Mathematica Code

```
ExpectationSteps[n_, p_] := Module[{eqns, sol, variables},
  variables = Table[X[i], {i, 0, n - 1}];
  eqns = 
   Table[X[i] == (1 + p (1 - p) X[Mod[i - 2, n]] + 
        p (1 - p) X[Mod[i + 2, n]])/(1 - p^2 - (1 - p)^2), {i, 1, 
     n - 1}];
  
  eqns = Join[eqns, {X[0] == 0}];
  sol = Solve[eqns, variables];
  Print[sol];
  ]
ExpectationSteps[9, 1/2]
```

After conducting several numerical experiments, I discovered that when $n$ is odd, $X_k$ has an integer solution for every $k$. This leads me to speculate that there might be some analytic solutions.

However, for even values of  $n$, the equations are inconsistent, as solutions exist only for a subset of $k$ values.

Comment: @Henry Yes. They move at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have four scenarios to consider separately to deal with the possibility of passing each other but not meeting when they pass: $n \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ with $k \equiv 0$ or $1 \pmod 2$; and $n \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ with $k \equiv 0$ or $1 \pmod 2$.

First consider a simpler case, where there are $m$ numbers and A stays stationary, while $B$ starts a distance $c$ steps away and moves $1$ either clockwise or or anti-clockwise.  You should be able to show the expected number of turns is $c(m-c)$.

Then take your actual question and your idea for approaching it.  You should be able to show the expected number of turns is double what it would be if A remains stationary and B moves $2$ steps forward with a probability of $0.5$ or  $2$ steps backward with a probability of $0.5$.  Then translate this into the answer for the simpler question.

For the various scenarios:

- $n$ even and $k$ even: you can use $m=\frac n2$ and $c=\frac k2$ (remembering the doubling) to get $2\frac k2(\frac n2-  \frac k2)$ $=\frac12k(n-k)$.
- $n$ even and $k$ odd: no meeting (as you have observed) though possibly some passing.
- $n$ odd and $k$ even, with $0 \le  k < \frac n2$: take $m=n$ and $c=\frac k2$ (this allows passing on the long way round but not on the short way) to get $2\frac k2( n-  \frac k2)$ $=\frac12k(2n-k)$.
- $n$ odd and $k$ odd, with $0 \le  k < \frac n2$: take $m=n$ and $c=\frac {n-k}2$ (this allows passing on the short way round but not on the long way) to get $2\frac {n-k}2( n- \frac {n-k}2)$ $=\frac12(n-k)(n+k)$.

The solutions which are not infinite are all integers.